# Asynchronous Performance Tests with XCTest

Tags: ios, unit-testing, asynchronous, xctest

I have started to explore the new XCTest APIs for asynchronous and performance testing. In isolation, the Apple examples from WWMC work well, but I have been unable to figure out how to combine them. The best I have been able to come up with is the following, but I receive the following error when it runs:

API violation - call made to wait without any expectations having been set.

```
XCTestExpectation *clsQueryReturnedExpectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"clsQuery returned"];

PFCLSClient *theClient = [[PFCLSClient alloc] init];

[self measureMetrics:@[XCTPerformanceMetric_WallClockTime] automaticallyStartMeasuring:YES forBlock: ^{
   [theClient getStructureOfType:clsImageTypeSVG ForID:idString success: ^(NSDictionary *structureInfo) {
       [clsQueryReturnedExpectation fulfill];
} failure: ^(NSError *error) {
       XCTFail();
       [clsQueryReturnedExpectation fulfill];
}];

   [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5 handler: ^(NSError *error) {
        [self stopMeasuring];
   }];
}];
```

Has anyone been able to accomplish something similar?

Thx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With some help from Apple, I have a solution. Silly oversight on my part as this is very easy to solve. To get to work, all you need to do is put the creating of the expectation object (clsQueryReturnedExpectation) inside the measureMetrics block so it is created afresh each time the performance test is run.

```
PFCLSClient *theClient = [[PFCLSClient alloc] init];

[self measureMetrics:@[XCTPerformanceMetric_WallClockTime] automaticallyStartMeasuring:YES forBlock: ^{
    XCTestExpectation *clsQueryReturnedExpectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"clsQuery returned"];  
    [theClient getStructureOfType:clsImageTypeSVG ForID:idString success: ^(NSDictionary *structureInfo) {
       [clsQueryReturnedExpectation fulfill];
    } failure: ^(NSError *error) {
       XCTFail();
       [clsQueryReturnedExpectation fulfill];
    }];

   [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5 handler: ^(NSError *error) {
        [self stopMeasuring];
   }];
}];
```

Comment: Is there anything else can be measured other than time? API reference seems to say that it take an array of XCTPerformanceMetrics but I can not find anything else anywhere to measure.

Comment: As far as I know, no you can't. I have read the same thing but think Apple just has not implemented anything at this point.